# Retrieving the row index of row pulled from datatable useing Linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am using the following query to pull a row from a datatable in memory.

```
Dim results = _
   From myRow In exceldt.AsEnumerable() _
   Where myRow.Field(Of String)("Serial Number") = Row.Item("Serial Number") _
   Select myRow

resultrow = results.CopyToDataTable.Rows(0)
```

I need to get the index of the resultrow when it was part of exceldt. I can't seem to find anything on this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't work in VB.net so forgive my code but you can get the index of a projection with something along the lines of this:

```
Dim result = exceldt.AsEnumerable() .Select (Function(item, index) _
  New With { .Index = index, .SerialNumber = item }).ToList
```

I can't provide much more with in VB but this quick example does work as a Console app. You can see how the select / projection captures the index and item. You will need to incorporate similar logic before filtering (where) you initial enumeration.

```
Dim names = {"Andy", "Tom", "Fred", "Sally"}

Dim results = names _
    .Select(Function(item, index) New With {.Index = index, .Name = item}) _
    .OrderBy(Function(item) item.Name)

For Each item In results
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Index, item.Name)
Next
```

results

```
0 - Andy
2 - Fred
3 - Sally
1 - Tom
```

Comment: This seems promising, but the syntax is off. Could you possibly run the code from the language you are used to through a converter? Or just add the code to your comment? I'm having difficulty deciphering.

Comment: I had a hard time implementing this so I went with a different option than Linq due to deadline, but it could very well be done using this option and is nicer than the option I used.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
int index = exceldt.Rows.IndexOf(results);
```

Comment: This seems to return -1 every time.

Comment: Here is a sample of the datatable you asked for ==> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Atss2136xoWIdGVpa1VOc3BqNmFISUNrM2lGZzVGVWc

Comment: Not familiar that much with vb but I think it's because you are checking against the result table instead of the actual original table

Comment: I have edited my original answer, this one should work better  ;)

Comment: results is the collection of rows returned by the query, not a table itself. exceldt is the original table.

Comment: Have you tried it ? That is exactly why you were receiveing -1 as a result, my suggestion was using the temporary datatable created to store the result. You should use the query result to retrieve the index because the query refers to the original table.

Comment: Of course I tried it, although I knew that it wouldn't work. Look at it. results is essentially a datatable that has only one row. If this were to even work, I would have to pass in the specific row index, in this case results.Row(0), but even that does not work.